# Why Google Pay doesn't work from iPhone Safary after an ajax request?

Tags: iphone, mobile-safari, google-pay

I try to add a Googla Pay button on a website. I follow the Google Pay implementation tutorial (https://developers.google.com/pay/api/web/guides/tutorial).

There is a code:

```
var paymentsClient = getGooglePaymentsClient();
paymentsClient.isReadyToPay(getGoogleIsReadyToPayRequest())
    .then(function(response) {
        //...
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
        //...
    });
```

I need to get some data from my server side before I call the above code so I do the http post request. Within success hanlder of my post request I call the above code. It works fine in my Android browser and my laptop browser. But it doesn't work from Safari. I get the "**Unexpected developer error please try again later**" error. If I call it without ajax request it works in Safari as well. Could someone suggest the solution?

Comment: Are you able to include a reproducible code sample with something like jsfiddle. If I had to guess, I'd say it's related to the API call being made in the `onClick` handler for the button.

Comment: thank you for your reply, I prepared jsfiddle for my problem. Please pay attention on $.post request. If I remove it my code start to work on my iPhone Safary. https://jsfiddle.net/vzh0u3kj/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for including the jsfiddle.

The reason that it's not working is because Google Pay tries to open a popup window when you call `loadPaymentData` in Safari. When a new window is triggered as the result of a click event (user initiated action), the popup window opens as expected. When it is triggered by a non-user initiated action, Google Pay gets loaded in the same window which ends up causing it to fail.

It looks like when you make an ajax request in the click handler and then call `loadPaymentData`, Safari considers it a non-user initiated action.

Check out the following [example](https://jsfiddle.net/tz0f641k//) in Safari:

```js
const ajaxButton = document.getElementById('ajax');
const nojaxButton = document.getElementById('nojax');

ajaxButton.addEventListener('click', event => {
  $.get('/echo/json/', () => {
    window.open('about:blank');
  });
});

nojaxButton.addEventListener('click', event => {
  window.open('about:blank');
});
```

I would recommend avoiding making any http calls on the button click event before `loadPaymentData`. If you can fetch the data before the button is clicked, then do so.

Out of interest, what kind of data are you fetching?

Comment: Thank you. I need get an orderId from the server. I don't have this one during loading because I'm not sure user will clisk the pay button and will pay. Getting orderId from my server helps me not to create useless records in the database.

Comment: You could create an order after you get a response from `loadPaymentData`.

Comment: Nope, I need to post orderId to Google as part of the payment data request accordint to documentation of my payment gateway (Vantiv)

Comment: Yes, when integrating via some payment processor gateway flow is: check if google pay is ready (can be used), fetch data paymentDataRequest from payment processor (data includes unique transactionId) and call loadPaymentData().

Answer (score 0):

I do not know what situation were 3 years ago but nowadays Safari blocks popup by default, but do not block popup opened after user interaction e.g. click and popup open (`window.open()`) within time < 1 second. Within that 1 second you can do anything - synchronous and asynchronous code (whatever callback, setTimeout, Promise.then(), async/await.

In our case to use that 1 sec. effectively we migrated JS Google Pay script loading in advance before user click button with Google Pay and our AJAX request to eur server on on behind payment processor server always takes less then 1 second.

Note very interesting thing to avoid Google Pay not working. When you are in code in ajax result and want to call PaymentsClient.loadPaymentData() you must call it in asynchronous way like `setTimeout(() => { PaymentsClient.loadPaymentData(...) }, 1)` or prepend noop e.g. `await sleepInMs(1)`. I do not know why it is exactly needed but it works. Without this hack popup window with google pay sheet is blocked and our page is redirected to pay.goole.com with error `OR_BIBED_15` which probably means popup was blocked - but I could not find error code definitions at all.